# Create SPL using Metaplex: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js

I'm trying to create a spl token on solana testnet using the following code.

```
export async function createToken(walletKeyPair: Keypair) {
    const umi = createUmi('https://api.testnet.solana.com');
    const myKeypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(walletKeyPair.secretKey);
    const myKeypairSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, myKeypair);
    umi.use(keypairIdentity(myKeypairSigner)).use(mplTokenMetadata());

    console.log('MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID', MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID);

    const mint = generateSigner(umi);
    await createAccountWithRent(umi, {
        newAccount: mint,
        space: 50,
        programId: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    console.log('Account created: ', mint.publicKey);

    const mintAccount = await umi.rpc.getAccount(mint.publicKey);
    assertAccountExists(mintAccount);

    const builder = createAndMint(umi, {
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        creators: [{ address: myKeypair.publicKey, verified: false, share: 100 }],
        payer: umi.payer,
        updateAuthority: umi.identity,
        authority: umi.identity,
        name: 'tokenName',
        symbol: 'tokenSymbol',
        uri: 'https://www.google.com',
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(90),
        decimals: 9,
        amount: 10_000,
        tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    });

    const response = await builder.sendAndConfirm(umi);

    console.log(response);
}
```

I know this could be done manually by using other libraries but im curious if it could be done like this. The mint account gets created and the actual `createAndMint` fails with the following error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/user/Github/repo/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5922:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/user/Github/repo/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5881:20)
    at async Object.sendTransaction (/Users/user/Github/repo/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi-rpc-web3js/src/createWeb3JsRpc.ts:327:25)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (/Users/user/Github/repo/node_modules/@metaplex-foundation/umi/src/TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)
    at async createToken (/Users/user/Github/repo/src/utils/create.token.ts:59:22)
    at async main (/Users/user/Github/repo/src/index.ts:6:5) {
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Error: BorshIoError',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 3505 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'
  ]
}
```

Udpate: just tried this implementation https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-create-a-fungible-spl-token-with-the-new-metaplex-token-standard and I get the same error

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're creating the mint account beforehand. The `create_v1` instruction will create the mint account for you and if it does not exist, it will check if the account is of a certain structure by de-serializing -- this is where I think your code fails.

So try removing the `createAccountWithRent` call in your code.

Comment: should I use `createMetadataAccountV3`? I mean latest stuff from metaplex

Comment: I get the same error when removing `createAccountWithRent`